# How to save user data in electron.js app?

Tags: sql, database, electron

I seek to save user data for my electron.js app. The app has a graph with adjustable values, which disappear when relaunching the app. Demo: 
https://puu.sh/Bx5Or/ffb0382d0c.gif

How do I preserve these values? Can (and should) it be done with SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a lot of modules to store data in an Electron app :

- http://lokijs.org
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- https://github.com/agershun/alasql
- https://github.com/amark/gun
- https://github.com/google/leveldb
- https://github.com/google/lovefield
- https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb
- https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval
- https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js
- https://github.com/localForage/localForage
- https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb
- https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb
- https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb
- https://github.com/typicode/lowdb
- https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB
- https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db
- https://github.com/TomPrograms/stormdb

I would suggest nedb which is pure JS and cross platform compatible.
The simplest is localStorage, which is browser native.
Or more simply, you can read/write data in a JSON file.

So, in your case, when the values are changed, save the data.
On start, get them from the database and put them in your adjustable values.